# Why is this JavaScript not working correctly?

Tags: javascript

Cannot work out why either of these are not working for me:

```
var Deck = function() {
  this.cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
};

var newDeck = new Deck

// console.log(newDeck()); // [1,2,3,4,etc]

console.log(newDeck.cards()); // [1,2,3,4,etc]
```

`returns newDeck.cards is not a function`

and

```
var Deck = function() {
  this.cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var cards = function(){
    console.log('hey')
  }
};

var newDeck = new Deck

// console.log(newDeck()); // [1,2,3,4,etc]

console.log(newDeck.cards()); // [1,2,3,4,etc]
```

`returns the same error as above`

I just want to return a function within an object from an instance

Comment: there is no function or method `cards`. `cards` is a property with an array. the right call would be `console.log(newDeck.cards);`

Comment: @NinaScholz there is a cards function in the second example though??

Comment: That's simply a local function, not a property of the instance.

Comment: Are you saying you *want* a function named `cards`? Because that will replace your array `cards`. In the second example, you define a local function but that in no way gives you a function on the instance.

Comment: I suggest to read a tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no function or method `cards`. `cards` is a property with an array. The right call would be

```
console.log(newDeck.cards);
```

```js
var Deck = function() {
    this.cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
};

var newDeck = new Deck;

console.log(newDeck.cards);
```

The second example holds a private function `cards`. Because of the private character, the function can not called outside.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this.cards` would be a property, not a function. If you want a function for all `Deck` instances:

```js
var Deck = function() {
    // `_cards` so we do not conflict with the `cards` function
    this._cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
};

Deck.prototype.cards = function() {
  return this._cards;
};

var deck = new Deck();
console.log(deck.cards());
```